# error in Cloud Build (GCP) - javac: invalid target release: 11

Tags: java, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I have a maven project which runs normally on my local computer, but when I push the code to the cloud repository, it fails in Cloud Build with the error below:

```
Step #0: [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
Step #0: [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
Step #0: [ERROR] javac: invalid target release: 11
Step #0: Usage: javac <options> <source files>
Step #0: use -help for a list of possible options
Step #0: 
Step #0: [INFO] 1 error
Step #0: [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
Step #0: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #0: [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
Step #0: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #0: [INFO] Total time:  18.785 s
Step #0: [INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-03T05:52:33Z
Step #0: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #0: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project job: Compilation failure
Step #0: [ERROR] javac: invalid target release: 11
Step #0: [ERROR] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ddd.dd</groupId>
    <artifactId>job</artifactId> 
    <version>1.0.0-RELEASE</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>job</name>
    <description>project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding> 
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies> 
        <!-- spring-boot-starter-web (spring-webmvc + tomcat) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- job-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xuxueli</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxl-job-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/ob_core-2.1.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <!-- kml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.29</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.9</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
  </configuration>
                 <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      
                      <mainClass>map.job.executor.JobExecutorApplication</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
                 
            </plugin>
        
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configurationFile>src/main/resources/mybatis/generator/generatorConfig.xml</configurationFile>
                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>8.0.29</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>tk.mybatis</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapper-generator</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/Test*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In the project structure (intellij idea) I've selected Java 11 (oracle) as SDK, in the modules -> dependencies I have done same. In the settings -> compiler, I selected java compiler and target bytecode as 11.  Also  $JAVA_HOME is : /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11. It runs on my local machine, however build fails in Cloud Build with the above error once I push my code.

Here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:11

WORKDIR /job
ADD ./target/xxxx-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar /job

EXPOSE 22 9999
ENV NAME job

CMD ["java","-jar", "-Duser.timezone=Australia/Sydney", "xxxx-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar"]
```

This is my `cloudbuild.yaml` file:

```
 steps:
# build the container image
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['install', '-Dmaven.test.skip=true']
# build the container image
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/xxxx-$_NAMESPACE:$BUILD_ID', '.']
  
  
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    for image_name in $(gcloud container images list); do
      for digest in $(gcloud container images list-tags $image_name --format=json | awk '/digest/{ print $2 }' | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/.\{2\}$//' | tail -n +6); do
          gcloud container images -q delete $image_name@$digest --force-delete-tags;
      done;
    done;
  
  # push the container image to Container Registry
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/xxxx-$_NAMESPACE:$BUILD_ID']
  # Deploy container image to Cloud Run

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    gcloud container clusters get-credentials oni-cluster --zone australia-southeast1-b
    sed -i.bak 's#IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER#gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/xxxx-$_NAMESPACE:$BUILD_ID#' ./k8s/sync/*.yaml
    sed -i.bak 's#NAMESPACE_PLACEHOLDER#$_NAMESPACE#' ./k8s/sync/*.yaml
    kubectl --namespace=$_NAMESPACE apply -f k8s/sync/

images:
- gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/xxxx-$_NAMESPACE:$BUILD_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

My project was build successful previously in GCP cloud build with bash script
but I got similar error yesterday - Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11

My solution was replace script with example:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-build-samples/blob/main/maven-example/cloudbuild.yaml

```
  - name: maven:3-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine
entrypoint: mvn
args: ['package','-Dmaven.test.skip=true']
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this. My project was also built successfully until a few days ago. Until that I was able to push my code to the same project and Cloud Build was running successfully